# Google API for getting maximum number of licenses in a Google Apps domain

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

I have a Google Apps Script function used for setting up accounts for new employees in our Google Apps domain.

The first thing it does is makes calls to the [Google Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#managing_general_domain_settings) and retrieves the **currentNumberOfUsers** and **maximumNumberOfUsers**, so it can see if there are available seats (otherwise a subsequent step where the user is created using the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) would fail).

It's been working fine until recently when our domain had to migrate from Postini to Google Vault for email archiving.

***Before*** the migration, when creating a Google Apps user using the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert), it would increment the **currentNumberOfUsers** by 1 and the new user account user would automatically have access to all Google Apps services.

***Now after*** the migration, when creating a Google Apps user, they aren't automatically assigned a "license," so I modified my script to use the [Enterprise License Manager API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/insert) and now it assigns a `"Google-Apps-For-Business"` license. That works fine.

However, the ***currentNumberOfUsers*** is now different from the *number of assigned licenses*, and `"Google-Apps-For-Business"` is only [one of several different types of licenses available](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products).

I can get the current number of ***assigned*** `"Google-Apps-For-Business"` licenses by running this:

```js
var currentXml = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.listForProductAndSku('Google-Apps', 'Google-Apps-For-Business', 'domain.com', {maxResults: 1000});
    
var current = currentXml.items.toString().match(/\/sku\/Google-Apps-For-Business\/user\//g).length;
```

But the number that produces is different from ***currentNumberOfUsers***.

All I really need to do now is get the ***maximum*** number of owned `"Google-Apps-For-Business"` licenses so the new employee setup script can determine whether there are any available.

I checked the API Reference documentation for the following APIs but...

[Enterprise License Manager API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/insert) → Doesn't have a method for getting the maximum or available number of licenses.

[Google Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#managing_general_domain_settings) → Doesn't deal with licenses, only "users."

[Admin SDK Directory API User resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) → Doesn't deal with licenses.

[Google Apps Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions#resource) → This API seems to have what I need, but [it's only for Reseller accounts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/prerequisites).

I know I can program my new employee setup script to just have a try/catch seeing if it would be able to create the user and assign the license, and end the script execution gracefully if it can't, but that doesn't seem efficient.

Also, part of the old script was that if there were less than X seats available, it would email me a heads-up to order more. I can program a loop that attempts to repeatedly create dummy users and assign them licenses and count the number of times it can do that before it fails, then delete all the dummy users, but, once again, that's not efficient at all.

Any ideas?

**Update 3/11/2020**: Since the Admin Settings API had shut down a few years ago I've been using the Enterprise License Manager API to get the current number of used licenses, like this:

```
function getCurrentNumberOfUsedGoogleLicenses(skuId) {

  var success = false, error = null, count = 0;

  var adminEmail = 'admin@domain.com';
  var gSuiteDomain = adminEmail.split('@')[1];

  // for more information on the domain-wide delegation:
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
  // the getDomainWideDelegationService() function uses this: 
  // https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2
  var service = getDomainWideDelegationService('EnterpriseLicenseManager: ', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.licensing', adminEmail);

  if (skuId == 'Google-Apps-Unlimited') var productId = 'Google-Apps';
  else                                  return { success: success, error: "Unsupported skuId", count: count };

  var requestBody                = {};
  requestBody.headers            = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()};
  requestBody.method             = "GET";
  requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;

  var data, pageToken, pageTokenString;

  var maxAttempts     = 5;
  var currentAttempts = 0;
  var pauseBetweenAttemptsSeconds = 3;

  loopThroughPages:
  do {

    if (typeof pageToken === 'undefined') pageTokenString = "";
    else                                  pageTokenString = "&pageToken=" + encodeURIComponent(pageToken);

    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/' + productId + '/sku/' + skuId + '/users?maxResults=1000&customerId=' + gSuiteDomain + pageTokenString;

    try {

      currentAttempts++;

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);

      var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

      if (result.items) {

        var licenseAssignments = result.items;
        var licenseAssignmentsString = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < licenseAssignments.length; i++) {

          licenseAssignmentsString += JSON.stringify(licenseAssignments[i]);

        }

        if (skuId == 'Google-Apps-Unlimited') count += licenseAssignmentsString.match(/\/sku\/Google-Apps-Unlimited\/user\//g).length;

        currentAttempts = 0; // reset currentAttempts before the next page

      }

    } catch(e) {

      error = "Error: " + e.message;

      if (currentAttempts >= maxAttempts) {

        error = 'Exceeded ' + maxAttempts + ' attempts to get license count: ' + error;

        break loopThroughPages;

      }

    } // end of try catch

    if (result) pageToken = result.nextPageToken;

  } while (pageToken);

  if (!error) success = true;

  return { success: success, error: error, count: count };

}
```

However, there still does not appear to be a way to get the maximum number available to the domain using this API.

Comment: It seems the only way to do this is to apply to get your account setup as a reseller.  Seems like an oversight to the ELM api.

Comment: That's what I figured, yeah. So I'm going to apply to be a reseller for myself. Unfortunately I think a Google Apps account can only have one reseller, so that means I'll have to drop my current reseller.

Comment: Update August 2016: We will no longer even be able to get the currentNumberOfUsers - Google has announced they're [shutting down the Admin Settings API](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/08/saying-goodbye-to-gdata-admin-settings.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [CustomerUsageReports](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/customerUsageReports/get).

jay0lee is kind enough to provide the [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) source code in Python. I crudely modified the `doGetCustomerInfo()` function into Apps Script thusly:

```
function getNumberOfLicenses() {
  var tryDate = new Date();
  var dateString = tryDate.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (tryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + tryDate.getDate().toString();
  while (true) {
    try {
      var response = AdminReports.CustomerUsageReports.get(dateString,{parameters : "accounts:gsuite_basic_total_licenses,accounts:gsuite_basic_used_licenses"});
      break;
    } catch(e) {
      //Logger.log(e.warnings.toString());
      tryDate.setDate(tryDate.getDate()-1);
      dateString = tryDate.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (tryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + tryDate.getDate().toString();
      continue;
    }
  };
  var availLicenseCount = response.usageReports[0].parameters[0].intValue;
  var usedLicenseCount = response.usageReports[0].parameters[1].intValue;
  Logger.log("Available licenses:" + availLicenseCount.toString());
  Logger.log("Used licenses:" + usedLicenseCount.toString());
  return availLicenseCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't actually get us the _current_ max number of licenses, it can only get the number from the admin reports, which show data from 2-4 days ago. This reporting delay causes problems in our system because it needs to be able to check the max number in real-time before it attempts to assign a license.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exploring [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) which is a tool that gives command line access to the administration functions of your domain.

Comment: Looks cool, I will definitely check that out. However as it is right now there's no way to utilize that in Google Apps Script functions. I'd have to figure out how to make calls to the GAM running on a publicly-accessible server and get responses in real-time.